# why i can't create grid layout inside custom dialog?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Hello everyone I have a Problem in creating "Grid Layout" inside 'Recyclerview' 
..

at the first I want to create Time slot [Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7W6w.png) but inside Custom Dialog using RecyclerView ..
SO

1/ I have a Fragment, in this fragment i create a button , I want when a button pressed the Dialog is Appear

2/ So i create a function for Custom Dialog (I also create custom layout) ..[NOTE  my dialog working without recyclerView code]

3/ And I create a recyclerView for time slot [NOTE: recyclerView working inside another activity it give me a result ]

BUT

4/ when I want to create that RecyclerView inside Dialog it give me an Error

(   `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException` )

this is the Function for Custom Dialog

```
public void DialogTime() {

    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_apointment_time, null);


    final Button btnOk = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.okb2);
    final Button btnCancle = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.cansleb2);


    alert.setView(mView);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
    alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);


 /////////////recyclerview////////

    RecyclerView dataList;
    List<String> titles;
    Adapter adapter;

    dataList = view.findViewById(R.id.dataList);

    titles = new ArrayList<>();


    int start=3;
    int end=6;


    int n=15;


    int resultOfCount=60/n;

    int resultOfHour=end-start;
    int totalResult=resultOfCount*resultOfHour;



    int m=0;  //mint akana

    //hamu au maw3idanay ka la start bo end hayaty
    for(int i=0 ;i<totalResult; i++) {

        if(m>45) {
            start ++;
            m=0;
        }



        if(m==0){
            titles.add(Integer.toString(start) +":"+"0"+Integer.toString(m) );
            System.out.println(Integer.toString(start) +":0"+Integer.toString(m));

        }
        else {
            titles.add(Integer.toString(start) +":"+Integer.toString(m) );
            System.out.println(Integer.toString(start) +":"+Integer.toString(m));

        }

        m = m + n;




    }



    adapter = new Adapter(getActivity(),titles);

    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),5,GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    dataList.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    dataList.setAdapter(adapter);









    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            alertDialog.dismiss();


        }
    });


    btnCancle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "cancle", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });



    alertDialog.show();


}
```

the Error Finding in this Line
( 
`dataList.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);`)

Comment: Consider reformatting your question in order to increase readability.
Using more uppercase letters would be a great start.

As next step for your debugging, find out which element is NULL, with the two candidates "dataList" and "gridLayoutManager". Then update your question accordingly :)

Comment: @Aiyion.Prime   Thanks for your comment....

Comment: Looks better, have you found which of the two variables is NULL?

Comment: @Aiyion.Prime no i haven't  :( i don't know which variables is NULL , but the Recycler code run perfectly in another Activity( Intent) so just in Custom dialog not run :(  please help me

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the complete stack trace that follows that first `FATAL EXCEPTION` line.

Comment: Ok, but what the question i should write?